# Make a Java boolean with a size of 1 bit

Tags: java, memory, boolean

I am writing a program which necessitates speed and a low memory overhead. In it, I have to make a 2d array of booleans, which will likely get very big.

In Java, I know that a boolean is an "overlay" to a char, so it takes up one byte.

Is there any way to make an array of booleans, each of which are only 1 bit, the storage space technically necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Use [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

Comment: He is concerned about optimization, won't BitSet be a bit much?

Comment: Start by thinking of a `char` as an array of 8 booleans.  And go from there.

Comment: Joe C, yeah depending on how many options he needs, he just needs to do OR and AND (or NOT).

Comment: See: [`boolean[]` vs. BitSet: Which is more efficient?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605226/5221149)

Comment: @JoeC, a `char` in Java has 16 bits, not 8.

Comment: Bit manipulation as a rule is slower than byte manipulation. So you have to choose between "speed" (whatever you mean by that) and "low" memory overhead (whatever you mean by that), but in this case you probably can't have both. And you should tell us how big "very big" is. "Very" is not an engineering concept. Put a number on it.

Comment: `I am writing a program which necessitates speed and a low memory overhead.` I wonder what made you choose Java then. :)

Comment: Definitely `BitSet`.  If it's two dimensional, a `BitSet[]` or a `List<BitSet>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already mentioned, you can use primitives as an array of bits. That is not straight forward to work with, but at least it reduces the amount of data that you store.

With the magic of method convertToBinary that I found here:
[Integer to binary array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151435/integer-to-binary-array)
We can work with such numbers easily.

e.g.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] flags = {
            0b0101_0101_0101_0101_0101_0101_0101_0101,
            0b0101_0101_0101_0101_0101_0101_0101_0101,
            0b0101_0101_0101_0101_0101_0101_0101_0101
    };
    for (Integer flag : flags) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getBooleanArray(flag)));
    }
}

private static boolean[] getBooleanArray(Integer value) {
    String valueAsString = Integer.toBinaryString(value).replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
    return convertToBinary(value, valueAsString.length());
}

private static boolean[] convertToBinary(int b, int size) {
    boolean[] binArray = new boolean[size];
    boolean bin;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (b % 2 == 1) bin = true;
        else bin = false;
        binArray[i] = bin;
        b /= 2;
    }
    return binArray;
}
```

Output:

```
[true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true]
```

[true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true]
[true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true]

Hope that helps.

Comment: In a question about efficiency you shouldn’t use `Integer` instead of `int`, not to speak of a `String` operation that can be replaced by a simple `32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value)`. Besides that, the `convertToBinary` method is broken. When bit 31 is set, the operations `%` and `/=` do not the intended thing, as the bit is interpreted as sign bit. Using real bit operations fixes the problem, simplifies the code, *and* makes it more efficient: `boolean[] binArray = new boolean[size];  for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--, b >>>= 1) { binArray[i] = (b & 1) != 0; }  return binArray;`

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a bit field. Java does not support bit fields.
Basically with C/C++ the compiler adds in the bit handling (1 << 2, 1<<3, etc) for you.

Good workaround: [Implementing a bitfield using java enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346477/implementing-a-bitfield-using-java-enums)

Comment: Yeah, [`java.util.BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) comes with Java, does the bit handling for you, takes about one bit of space per `boolean`, and works nicely.