# How to use query parameter with different combination in rest assured in Java?

Tags: java, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have 6 query parameters. All of them are optional.
How should I use them with all combinations?
I tried the following:

```
do {
    Response searchbyfield = given()
   .headers("Cookie", cookies)
   .queryParam("search","test")
   .queryParam("is_phone_verified",String.valueOf(is_phone_verified))
   .queryParam("is_mail_verified",String.valueOf(is_mail_verified))
   .queryParam("is_doc_verified",String.valueOf(is_doc_verified))
   .queryParam("taxform",String.valueOf(taxform))
   .queryParams("page", String.valueOf(page))
   .when().get("")
   page = page + 1;
    }
 while (next.contains("page"));
```

I used this method but it's not generic.
I'm wondering how I can make one function and cover all combinations?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a set of parameters and two states of them (either they enabled or not). That means that you have `2^n` combinations where `n` is the total amount of your parameters.

Hence the solution would be to iterate from `0` to `2^n-1`, convert the current number into binary representation and build your `RequestSpecification` accordingly.

[image]

Let's break by steps.

**0. Lets have the `Parameter` class that would hold our key-value**

```java
class Parameter {
    String key;
    Object value;

    public Parameter(String key, Object value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**1. Convert a number to binary representation.** See [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8151674).

```java
boolean[] getCombination(int rowNum, int bits){
    boolean[] flags = new boolean[bits];
    for (int i = bits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        flags[i] = (rowNum & (1 << i)) != 0;
    }
    return flags;
}
```

**2. Now we can build a flag mask that would hold enable/disable flag for all combinations**

```java
boolean[][] getCombinations(Parameter[] parameters){
    int rowNum = (int)Math.pow(2, parameters.length);
    boolean[][] results = new boolean[rowNum][parameters.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++){
        boolean[] line = getCombination(i, parameters.length);
        for(int j = 0; j < parameters.length; j++){
            results[i][j] = line[j];
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

**3. Finally we can generate `RequestSpecification` with required mask**

```java
RequestSpecification generateCombination(RequestSpecification original, 
                                         Parameter[] parameters, 
                                         boolean[] flags){
    RequestSpecification changed = original;
    for(int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++){
        Parameter p = parameters[i];
        if(flags[i]){
            changed = changed.queryParam(p.getKey(), p.getValue());
        }
    }
    return changed;
}
```

**-- How to use all that**

Assume that you have all these methods implemented in `ParamTest` class. Then you could test the solution by adding following main method to it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParamTest paramTest = new ParamTest();
    Parameter[] parameters = {
            new Parameter("name1", "val1"),
            new Parameter("name2", 123),
            new Parameter("name3", List.of("a", "b", "c"))
    };
    RequestSpecification originalSpec = RestAssured.given();
    boolean[][] mask = new ParamTest().getCombinations(parameters);
    for(int i = 0; i < mask.length; i++){
        if(mask[i].length != parameters.length){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected size of array");
        }
        paramTest
                .generateCombination(originalSpec, parameters, mask[i])
                .get() // Do here what you want;
        ;
    }
}
```

So that:

1. You create an instance of the class
2. You define the list of parameters
3. You prepare original `RequestSpecification` that you'll be customizing in further loop
4. You obtain flag mask array
5. You iterate through that flag mask array, obtain particular customized specification that has only certain set of parameters and apply the check that you want.